# SQLAlchemy: Querying compound primary key with `IN` operator

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, compound-key

Assuming a table `foo` with compound primary key `(a,b)`, How I can generate following sql query with SQLAlchemy (postgresql dialect)?

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE (a,b) IN ((1,2), (2,3));
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```python
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import Tuple
session.query(Foo).filter(Tuple(Foo.a, Foo.b).in_([(1,2), (3,4)])).all()
```